# Retrieve bound value in angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know the same angular attribute directive can be bound a number of ways:

> data-hello-world, x-hello-world and hello:world are all valid attributes for binding the helloWorld attribute directive.

In the link function for my directive, how do I know which of these attribute keys was used?

So, if my html is:

```
<div data-hello-world="hi"></div><div hello:world="bye"></div>
```

and my directive is:

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs[???]);
        }
    }
});
```

how do I know which attribute to look for in the directive so that the correct value gets logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div data-hello-world="hi" one="bye">
</div>


app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs.one); // bye
   console.log(attrs.helloWorld); // hi
    }
}
});
```

Here 'helloWord' directive is used as an attribute. so that the value assigned to "data-hello-world" which is "hi" will be found in parameter called attrs defined in link function. Same time it will look for other attributes mentioned with helloWorld directive. here i've mentioned 'one' attribute and this can also be found in attrs parameter defined in link function. you can get attributes' values from attrs parameter. (And yes there are mulitple ways to bound a value as you have mentioned in your description)

any further question, raise your question and answer will be given.

Comment: +1 for explanation :) please remove the last line. thats not mandatary

Comment: is there anyway in the link function to retrieve the "helloWorld" directive name as a variable (so I could use the same link function in multiple directives).

Comment: i dont understand your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Angular directives access attributes and scope from the view using camel cased naming convention without the special characters. See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

> Directives have camel cased names such as ngBind. The directive can be
>   invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these
>   special characters :, -, or _. Optionally the directive can be
>   prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XWQ95meVIrJQKZdNYTf4?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs['helloWorld']);
        }
    }
});
```